# Came "into" fruition?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

My friend wrote some copy, explaining that her "company came into fruition because she realized the opportunity..."

I've never used "came into fruition" -- only "came to fruition".  Is "came into fruition" a proper phrase in any context?  Regardless, I don't believe "fruition" is appropriate for her meaning, as it does not denote origin.  I would say "came into existence," "came into being" or "came to be".

Thoughts?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=into+fruition%2Cto+fruition&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinto%20fruition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20fruition%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's quite true ***to*** is far more common, but given [an estimated 2,730 results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22came+into+fruition%22) in Google Books, I don't think *came **into** fruition* can be meaningfully classified as "wrong".

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=came+into+fruition%2Ccame+to+fruition&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccame%20into%20fruition%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccame%20to%20fruition%3B%2Cc0) are even more convincing (for 'BrE'). And I'd agree about 'came to fruition' being idiomatic, but inappropriate here.

Comment: Since fruition has the sense of _turning into_, we don't need another _into_. But with _fortuitous_ so often used to mean _fortunate_, and _literally_ to mean _not literally but almost_, I'd let it pass. Doesn't mean I would use it.

Comment: _Fruition_ itself has a somewhat unusual history. Noah Webster, _A Compendious Dictionary of the English Language_ (1806) has this brief entry for the word: "**Fruition**, _n._ enjoyment, possession, pleasure." The word for "the act of bearing, fruitfulness" according to that dictionary was _fructification_. The association of _fruition_ with the meaning "bearing fruit" doesn't appear in a _Webster's Collegiate Dictionary_ until the fifth edition (1936). which attributes the emergence of this new meaning to "confusion with _fruit_."